# Python MySQL- Queries are being unexpectedly cached

Tags: python, mysql

I have a small issue(for lack of a better word) with MySQL db. I am using Python.
So I have this table in which rows are inserted regularly. As regularly as 1 row /sec.
I run two Python scripts together. One that simulates the insertion at 1 row/sec. I have also turned autocommit off and explicitly commit after some number of rows, say 10.

The other script is a simple "SELECT count(*) ..." query on the table. This query doesn't show me the number of rows the table currently has. It is stubbornly stuck at whatever number of rows the table had initially when the script started running. I have even tried "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) ..." to no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you query the database directly via the mysql console can you see the inserts?

Comment: @learningJava-Yes. I can see the inserts when querying the db from the MySQL console.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya-The code does nothing special as such. One script just inserts rows in the table. Another script just queries the table. I run them both simultaneously. I don't know if that helps, but I assure you I am not doing anything special in the code.

Comment: If your table is innodb, then you have to manually commit the transaction for anything to actually happen.

Comment: @user1292090 if nothing special was happening in the code you wouldn't need to be asking about why it's doing special things… ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If autocommit is turned off in the reader as well, then it will be doing the reads inside a transaction and thus not seeing the writes the other script is doing.

Comment: @KernelM-This worked. The Python MySQL API automatically turns autocommit to False. I set autocommit to true and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you're using INNODB with `REPEATABLE READ` isolation mode. Try setting the isolation mode to `READ COMMITTED`:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

Another way is starting a new transaction every time you perform a `select` query. [Read more here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html)

Comment: This is my suspicion as well.

Comment: @Dikei-I did try your solution. I executed this sql statement from inside the script that was doing the inserts before I started any of the inserts. I hope that was how you meant it to be done. That didn't solve the issue. I was still not able to read the inserts the writer was making from my reader script. But KernelM's solution worked. I had to set autocommit to true in the reader also to be able to read the inserts. In his response he has mentioned a reason why this happens also.
Thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: You have to set this in the `select` script :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that either the reader or writer (most likely the writer) is operating inside a transaction which hasn't been committed. Try ensuring that the writer is committing after each write, and try a `ROLLBACK` from the reader to make sure that it isn't inside a transaction either.

Comment: KernelM's solution to the problem worked. It seems autocommit has to be set to true even in the reader if it has to read the inserts that the writer is making!
Thanks a lot for your response!